# Implementing a stack through a single linked list

Tags: java, stack

I'm having trouble implementing a `stack` through a `single linked list`:

Here's the interface i'm implementing:

```
public interface Stack<E> {

    /**
     * element at the top without removing it
     */
    public E peek();

    /**
     * pop from the stack
     */
    public void pop();

    /**
     * insert into the stack
     */
    public void push( E e );

    /**
     * isEmpty
     */
    public boolean isEmpty();

    /**
     * size
     */
    public int size();

    /**
     * reverse
     */
    public Stack<E> reverse();

}
```

and here's my implementation:

```
public class ListStack<E> implements Stack<E> {

    private static class Node<T> {
        private T item;
        private Node<T> next;

        private Node(T item, Node<T> next) {
            this.item = item;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    private Node<E> first;
    private int size;


    public ListStack() {
        this.size = 0;
        this.first = null;
    }

    @Override
    public E peek() {
        return first.item;
    }

    @Override
    public void pop() {
        first = first.next;
        size--;
    }

    @Override
    public void push(E e) {

        Node<E> node = new Node<E>(e, first);
        first = node;
        size++;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {

        return (first == null);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {

        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public Stack<E> reverse() {

    }

}
```

I'm struggling with the `reverse` method, and i'm not sure if i'm programming this right.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you give us an example of the input and faulty output, along with the desired output? Or an explanation of how the reverse method is screwing up.

Comment: @JonnyHenly actually i just noticed that for any type of data inserted, the stack is always null, so maybe something is wrong there, i just don't know where

Comment: take a look at your pop method, should it not set a temporary variable to hold E and then set first equal to next and then return the temporary E?

Comment: the `pop()` me should not return anything @JonnyHenly it has to be void. but yes i definitely did that mistake there, thanks!

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: @Radiodef the reverse method i don't know how to do that, and i just wanted to know if my implementation was correct

Comment: Do you have to return a new reversed stack or reverse the existing stack in-place?

Comment: a new reversed stack @Ma3x

Comment: @laker001: Good. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reverse an existing stack all you have to do is follow the Node.next references of your existing stack and push items on the new stack along the way.

```
@Override
public Stack<E> reverse()
{
    ListStack<E> reversed = new ListStack<E>();

    Node<E> node = first;
    while(node != null)
    {
        reversed.push(node.item);
        node = node.next;
    }

    return reversed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just so i know my other methods are okay ?

Comment: Yes, they look right.